# How to set different colors each rows based on the number of spaces?

Tags: regex, yaml, syntax-highlighting, sublime-text-plugin, sublimetext4

I want to change the text color to red on a line if it has 4 spaces, blue color if it has 8 spaces, 12 spaces to green and so on. I'm using `.YAML` format to achieve this, but the text always set to red color no matter how many spaces in the beginning of the line.

These are how I tried:

```
- match: ^\s{4}[\w\d_\.', ]*$
  scope: indent_1

- match: ^\s{8}[\w\d_\.', ]*$
  scope: indent_2

- match: ^\s{12}[\w\d_\.', ]*$
  scope: indent_3
```

Apparently, this code sets the whole texts to red

```
text 1 (red)
    text 2 (red)
        text 3 (red)
```

Second try, I combined 2 matches using capture keywords

```
- match: \s{4}[\w\d_\.', ]*$
  captures:
    1: indent_1
    2: indent_2
  push:
    - match: \s{4}, 
      scope: indent_1
    - match: $
      pop: true
  push:
    - match: \s{8}, 
      scope: indent_2
    - match: $
      pop: true
```

This throws an error;

> error: Error loading syntax file "Packages/note/note.sublime-syntax": Error trying to parse sublime-syntax: Duplicate key in mapping in :35:7

Another try, I added `OR(|)` operator in between the `\s{n}` expressions, but this code sets its color to only the spaces in the beginning of the lines.

```
- match: (\s{4})|(\s{8})[\w\d_\.', ]*$
  captures:
    1: indent_1
    2: indent_2
  push:
    - match: \s{4}
      scope: indent_1
    - match: $
      pop: true
    - match: \s{8}
      scope: indent_2
    - match: $
      pop: true


    (color black) text 1
        (color black) text 2
            (color black) text 3
```

Are there any ways to fix this problem?

Comment: Perhaps try `^[^\S\r\n]{8}[\w.',][\w.', ]*$` or 8 spaces `^[ ]{8}[\w.',][\w.', ]*$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird This only works when it's alone inside of the code. If I put the code with the rest of others, `indent_1` still gets any lines that have greater than 4 spaces.

Comment: Did you also change 4 spaces to this? `^[ ]{4}[\w.',][\w.', ]*$`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I missed that one. Now it works. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using this pattern:

```
^\s{4}[\w\d_\.', ]*$
```

Here `\s` can also match newlines, and the character class `[\w\d_\.', ]` can also match a space.

So the pattern matches at least 4 whitespace characters, but it can also match a space after it and this pattern will then match for all the cases.

Note that `\w` also matches `\d` and `_` and you don't have to escape the dot `\.` in the character class.

Matching whitespace chars without newlines instead of a single space could be done with `[^\S\r\n]` or for example `\h` if that is supported. Then you would for example also match 8 tabs.

If you want to start the match with 4 spaces, and there has to be at least a single char from the character class following that is not a space:

```
^[ ]{4}[\w.',][\w.', ]*$
```

The pattern matches:

- `^` Start of string
- `[ ]{4}` Match 8 spaces (the square brackets are for clarity only)
- `[\w.',]` Match a single word char or `.` `'` `,`
- `[\w.', ]*` Match optional word chars or `.` `'` `,` or a space
- `$` End of string

Then the second pattern will be matching 8 spaces etc..

```
^[ ]{8}[\w.',][\w.', ]*$
```

Comment: I see. I always get confused how regex and its combinations work. Thanks for explanations with clear descriptions.